# Clear input value Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two radio buttons, foreach radio button I have text input fields. I add this ------- like a default value for text input fields. All I want is to remove this value when the second radio is checked.

My code is:

```
if (jQuery('.product-options .display ul li:nth-child(1)').find('input').is(':checked')) {
        jQuery(".product-options dd input.input-text").attr('value', '--------');
        jQuery(".product-options dd input.input-text").addClass('validation-passed');
}

jQuery('.product-options .display ul li:nth-child(1)').find('input').change(function(){
    if (jQuery(this).is(':checked')) {
            jQuery(".product-options dd input.input-text").attr('value', '--------');
            jQuery(".product-options dd input.input-text").addClass('validation-passed');

    }

})

jQuery('.product-options .display ul li:nth-child(2)').find('input').change(function(){
    if (jQuery(this).is(':checked')) {
            jQuery(".product-options dd input.input-text").attr('value', '');
    }
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `.val('')` to set the value of an input, not `.attr('value', '')`.

Comment: no is not work, I have this in magento, and when I clear the value this is not saved when I press Add to Cart in the log file the input field have the blank value not what I type

Answer (score 0):

First of all your code is a mess. You should at least shorten the selectors, it's hard to read them. Second, I have some issues to understand what is your problem.

Some comments based on your code.

1) You're changing same input in both cases. No matter which button is checked, you still searching for the same elements via 
`jQuery(".product-options dd input.input-text")`

2) What amphetamachine's said - you should use `.val('')` to clear value of the input. Your value is blank, because of my 1st point. You're simply doing your selection wrong.

Comment: Hi, I am not an expert in javascript, for that I put here my code and my question, the idea is like this, this text input fields are blank by default, I need to add something in the first and remove it when the second radios is checked

Comment: Do you need to clear both text inputs when second radio button is checked? Or just 1st one? Or do you need to clear an opposite text field(like if you check 2nd radio button, 1st text-input clears, and if you check 1st radio, 2nd text-field clears)?

Comment: I need to clear only the second when is check, and the first is need to remain with the characters ------

Comment: and if I use .val('') there is nothing happened

Comment: let me to explain you again, when first radio is check the text field is hidden, and I need to have this  characters: ---- there in the value attribute, when the second radio is check I need to clear this value

Comment: if your field is hidden, why do you use text-field instead of hidden field? Can you please make an example of your code on jsbin, so I can see it?